# Can't connect to socket.io server from phone (phonegap apk)

Tags: android, azure, cordova, socket.io, phonegap

It works using browser, but when I build apk and install it to the phone.. it doesn't connect to server.

Server code:

```
var http = require('http'); 
var port = process.env.port || 80; 

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }); 
    res.end('Hello World 2.14'); 
}).listen(port);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('user connected'); // Server receive this log if it's opened with browser, but NO response using APK.
});
```

Client is connecting using this code:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://irvelbandom01.azurewebsites.net');
```

I changed confix.xml so it would allow to connect to azure domain:

```
<access origin="https://irvelbandom01.azurewebsites.net*" />
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Still dont know why but after I changed the path it works!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
```